# How to trigger custom action when social media button has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-plus, facebook-sharer, social-media

I want to create a social media div locker. When a user comes to my site a piece of text is hidden behind a div locker that says "share this stuff on facebook, G+ or Twitter and you will see the locked text".

So, I want to make the hidden div visable after the visitor has pressed one of the social media buttons and actually shared it. How can I do it? I understand it has something to do with listening if the social media button has been pressed or smth.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [FB.Events.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) library.

Comment: But I want to use Twitter and G+ also. Do they have also these libraries?